# Magic Link is expired when using outlook - Nextauth

Tags: next.js, outlook, next-auth

We launched our product yesterday and some users reported that when they click on the magic link for the login, this is expired. That is cause by safety links from Microsoft. We don't want our users to deactivate this function, since not all IT departments would want that. We found this: https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/avoid-corporate-link-checking-email-provider as possible documentation but it seems incomplete. Does anyone here has experience with this? thanks!!

we tried different browsers and also different security features

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is to avoid using links that don't require an action - do not assume an end user is the only way the link can be hit. Make the link point to a page that requires an explicit user action, such clicking a button that submits a form - link crawlers don't do do POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems pretty complete to me. As mentioned in the docs, you only have to edit the `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file to add this snippet to the very beginning of the function :

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

  // Return a successful response to any HTTP request to this endpoint with the HEAD method
  if(req.method === "HEAD") {
     return res.status(200).end()
  }

  // This is your current auth handler with your options
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    ...
  })
}
```

This will essentially return a successful HTTP status for any HTTP requests that use the method `HEAD` sent to your endpoint, without using up the authentication link provided in the email.

Since the Outlook client is only sending these `HEAD` requests to your link, this should fix the problem.